# Cannot use ContextTransactionalCallable with TransactionProvider

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I have an error, which I can't solve.

I am using Spring and JOOQ.

Error occurs here:

```
   @Transactional
    public UUID create(List<User> users) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        dslContext.transaction(() -> {
            dslContext
                    .insertInto(APPLE, APPLE.APPLE_ID, APPLE.TITLE)
                    .values(uuid, uuid.toString())
                    .execute();

            users.forEach(user -> {
                dslContext
                        .insertInto(APPLE_MEMBERS, APPLE_MEMBERS.APPLE_ID, APPLE_MEMBERS.USER_ID)
                        .values(uuid, user.getUserId())
                        .execute();
            });

        });

        return uuid;
    }
```

Error:

```
org.jooq.exception.ConfigurationException: Cannot use ContextTransactionalCallable with TransactionProvider of type class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.SpringTransactionProvider
```

Maybe someone had same error or has idea how to solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using out of the box features:

You have to pick one of the two approaches:

- Spring's declarative transaction management through annotations
- jOOQ's programmatic transaction management through its API

Out of the box, they cannot be combined. In your particular case, I don't see why you would want to do it. The nested, programmatic transaction has the exact same scope as the outer, declarative transaction. It is redundant.

#### Using custom `TransactionProvider` implementations

You could write your own `TransactionProvider` that is able to communicate with Spring's transaction management and allows for embedding nested transactions in `@Transactional` annotated methods, but I generally advise against it. Pick one of the two approaches.

Comment: FYI, I bumped into this one again, after a year or so, and could not remember why we have this strange manual Spring Tx code inside jOOQ code... Turns out some method begins as non-transactional, then switches to transactional for a looped chunked insert (via calling local private methods). That's annoying to do with `@Transactional` because [by default it's only supported on `public methods`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html). I'll comment our code. Using a jOOQ transaction there would be lovely, but I can see why it's hard.

Comment: Among other things, jOOQ automatically turns off autocommit, then turns it on again. I hate doing all this plumbing. Finally sorted it all out. Sometimes it needs to be much more involved than we'd like it to be.

Comment: ...which Spring does, of course, too. Or it should. It doesn't in some rather peculiar circumstances. I'll file a bug somewhere.

Comment: Eh :-) I'll be looking for the report. Or not, if it was Spring :)

Comment: As @LukasEder pointed out, you have to pick one of the two alternatives. However, if it's essential for you to use programmatic transactions like in your code, you can use spring's interface for transaction management instead of jooq's. Just inject `TransactionTemplate` into your implementation (it's auto-configured in spring-boot applications)

Comment: @systemfreund: Very good! We'll add that option to various examples and documentation: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9430. It seems to be almost equivalent but works much better with Spring, out of the box.